# Не подключается функция в PyQT6

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, pyqt6, qcombobox

Необходимо создать зависимые списки в интерфейсе программы, чтобы при выборе в первом `comboBox` подтягивался определённый список, во втором `comboBox`, при этом это результат  должен отражаться в `label`, а кнопка должна копировать эти значения в буфер. Я сделал и это работало.

Но там была другая проблема (не наследовался интерфейс). И так я почитал и нашел  как сделать отдельно оригинальный файл и сами функции.

Кнопка копирования работает, а вот функции для `comboBox` ни как не могу подключить.

Суть функционала - пользователь выбирает в первом `comboBox` значение, и во второй `comboBox` ему подтягивается список, данные подтягиваются из словаря `data` (ключ в первый `comboBox`, а значения в второй `comboBox`). Выбор делается за счет цикла `for`.

---

Сам интерфейс выглядит вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Код который сделан в *Qt Designer*

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(365, 344)
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(223, 149, 236, 45), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));")
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Plain)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
    self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 11)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.frame)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.comboBox.setFont(font)
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.frame)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.label_2.setFont(font)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame)
    self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
    self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(parent=self.frame_2)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 641, 151))
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.textEdit.setFont(font)
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_2)
    self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
    self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
    self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Plain)
    self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame_3)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.label_3.setFont(font)
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.frame_3)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(16)
    self.pushButton.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_3)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

Код с функциями куда подключен файл сделанный с *Qt Designer*

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from appRT_test import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copyToClipboard)

        # add data
        for key, val in data.items():
            item_key = QStandardItem(key)
            self.model.appendRow(item_key)
            for value in val:
                item_value = QStandardItem(value)
                item_key.appendRow(item_value)

        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateItemCombo)
        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.description_teg)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.item_label)
        self.updateItemCombo(0)

        self.show()

    def updateItemCombo(self, index):
        indx = self.model.index(index, 0, self.ui.comboBox.rootModelIndex())
        self.ui.comboBox_2.setRootModelIndex(indx)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def item_label(self):
        text_label = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        text_label2 = self.ui.comboBox_2.currentText()
        self.ui.label.setText(text_label + ' ' + text_label2)

    def copyToClipboard(self):
        cb = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear()
        cb.setText(self.ui.label.text())

    def description_teg(self, index):
        if index == 1:
            self.ui.label_2.setText('Описание: ' + description_date[0])
        if index == 2:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(description_date[1])
        if index == 3:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(description_date[2])

data = {'item 0': '', 'item 1': ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3'], 'item 2': ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3'], 'item 3': ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3']}

description_date = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

---

Код, в котором работает  функция:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(693, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.MainComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.MainComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.MainComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.MainComboBox.setObjectName("MainComboBox")
        self.OfComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.OfComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 261, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.OfComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.OfComboBox.setObjectName("OfComboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 80, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 152, 681, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 152, 681, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label2.setFont(font)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "TestComboBox"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Choice"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # add button
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copyToClipboard)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        # add ComboBox
        # self.MainComboBox.setFixedSize(210, 40)
        self.MainComboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.MainComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.MainComboBox.setObjectName("MainComboBox")
        self.MainComboBox.setModel(self.model)

        self.OfComboBox.setFixedSize(210, 40)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.OfComboBox.setFont(font)
        self.OfComboBox.setObjectName("OfComboBox")
        self.OfComboBox.setModel(self.model)

        # add data
        for key, val in data.items():
            item_key = QStandardItem(key)
            self.model.appendRow(item_key)
            for value in val:
                item_value = QStandardItem(value)
                item_key.appendRow(item_value)

        self.MainComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateItemCombo)
        self.MainComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.description_teg)
        self.OfComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.item_label)
        self.updateItemCombo(0)

        # add ComboBox in Wiget
        layout.addWidget(self.MainComboBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        layout.addWidget(self.OfComboBox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def updateItemCombo(self, index):
        indx = self.model.index(index, 0, self.MainComboBox.rootModelIndex())
        self.OfComboBox.setRootModelIndex(indx)
        self.OfComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def item_label(self):
        text_label = self.MainComboBox.currentText()
        text_label2 = self.OfComboBox.currentText()
        self.label.setText(text_label + ' ' + text_label2)

    def copyToClipboard(self):
        cb = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear()
        cb.setText(self.label.text())

    def description_teg(self, index):
        if index == 1:
            self.label2.setText('Описание: ' + description_date[0])
        if index == 2:
            self.label2.setText(description_date[1])
        if index == 3:
            self.label2.setText(description_date[2])

data = {'item 0': '', 'item 1': ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3'], 'item 2': ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3'], 'item 3': ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3']}

description_date = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Не работает вот эта часть

```
    for key, val in data.items():
        item_key = QStandardItem(key)
        self.model.appendRow(item_key)
        for value in val:
            item_value = QStandardItem(value)
            item_key.appendRow(item_value)

    self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateItemCombo)
    self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.description_teg)
    self.ui.comboBox_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.item_label)
    self.updateItemCombo(0)

    self.show()

def updateItemCombo(self, index):
    indx = self.model.index(index, 0, self.ui.comboBox.rootModelIndex())
    self.ui.comboBox_2.setRootModelIndex(indx)
    self.ui.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)

def item_label(self):
    text_label = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
    text_label2 = self.ui.comboBox_2.currentText()
    self.ui.label.setText(text_label + ' ' + text_label2)
```

Кнопка копирования подключилась без вопросов и работает. Те данные из справочника не подтягивается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте комбобоксам модели.

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# так:
#from appRT_test import Ui_MainWindow                       
# или так:
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(365, 344)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(223, 149, 236, 45), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Plain)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 11)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame)
        
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(parent=self.frame_2)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 641, 151))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Plain)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.frame_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_3)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
# -------------------------------------------------------------> vvvvvvv <-----vvv------        
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",   "TextLabel label"  ))# + для теста
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel label_2"))# + для теста
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel label_3"))# + для теста

        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

# так:
'''                                     vvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    ...
        self.setupUi(self)
    ...
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copyToClipboard)
    ...
'''
# или так:
'''
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()                               # !!! 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    ...
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copyToClipboard)
    ...
'''
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.copyToClipboard)

        # add data
        for key, val in data.items():
            item_key = QStandardItem(key)
            self.model.appendRow(item_key)
            for value in val:
                item_value = QStandardItem(value)
                item_key.appendRow(item_value)

# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.ui.comboBox.setModel(self.model)        
        self.ui.comboBox_2.setModel(self.model)        
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateItemCombo)
        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.description_teg)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.item_label)
        self.updateItemCombo(0)

#        self.show()

    def updateItemCombo(self, index):
        indx = self.model.index(index, 0, self.ui.comboBox.rootModelIndex())
        self.ui.comboBox_2.setRootModelIndex(indx)
        self.ui.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def item_label(self):
        text_label = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()
        text_label2 = self.ui.comboBox_2.currentText()
        self.ui.label.setText(text_label + ' ' + text_label2)

    def copyToClipboard(self):
        cb = QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear()
        print(f'def copyToClipboard(self): {self.ui.label.text()}') #
        cb.setText(self.ui.label.text())

    def description_teg(self, index):
        if index == 1:
            self.ui.label_2.setText('Описание: ' + description_date[0])
        if index == 2:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(description_date[1])
        if index == 3:
            self.ui.label_2.setText(description_date[2])


data = {
    'item 0': '', 
    'item 1': ['item 1.1', 'item 1.2', 'item 1.3'], 
    'item 2': ['item 2.1', 'item 2.2', 'item 2.3'], 
    'item 3': ['item 3.1', 'item 3.2', 'item 3.3']
}

description_date = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: label_3 пока не задействовал, там текущая дата и время будет по плану, пока до этого не добрался.  Да, подключение моделей я упустил.